# Blurry display with two graphic cards?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card

I recently bought a new Windows 10 laptop, but much of its display is quite blurry. Its display is actually not as smooth as my old laptop, which is several years old.

My system recognizes two graphic cards:

1. Intel HD Graphics 620
2. Radeon R7 M445

Could the drivers of these cards be conflicting with one another?

Comment: Is the display in it's native resolution? Often if it isn't the display seems out of focus. I highly doubt the drivers are conflicting with each other. Most likely cause if the resolution is set correctly is the laptop is defective.

Comment: The resolution is at its "recommended" setting. I have not messed with it as of yet, so I do not think that's the problem.

Comment: Then you most likely have a defective unit, try connecting an external monitor that is known good and I bet it works as expected.

Comment: What is your DPI setting set at?

Comment: Drivers could be an issue, especially with the Radeon. Generic Windows drivers can cause a "blurry" look with AMD graphics hardware. You should install official AMD drivers from their website.